Help with a venom/poison ranged D&D 3.5
Can you guys help me with a build for ranged attacks infused? DM allows all 3.5 books. Was looking for a strong venom build

This question will likely see more success if it’s framed as “what are the approaches to optimizing ranged poison damage?” since we can’t really create a singular build for a concept that wide. That, or a lot more detail on exactly what you’re looking for so that we can create a singular build.

Alternatively, try a forum which is a lot more suited for broad questions like these. I'd love to help you out with some links to appropriate forums, but I haven't played 3.5 in a long time and don't know what's active any more.

Welcome! To help us help you, please [edit] in as much information as possible, such as the levels you expect to play at, expected magic items, etc. Happy gaming!

The best resource for D&D 3.5e poison is the Arsenic and Old Lace Handbook. It can give you a lot of options for the best poisons to use, the best ways to get them, the best ways to apply them, and so on. It also has sample builds you could consider and use.
Natural venom vs. applied poison
Many creatures automatically apply poison on bite or sting attacks, without having to manually “apply” that venom to their attack. This is a huge advantage, because manually applying poison takes time and risks poisoning yourself, plus applied poisons get expensive. On the other hand, you’re also locked in to whatever venom your body (currently) produces; manually-applied poisons can have far greater variety. Also, the overwhelming majority of natural venoms apply only to specific attacks, like bites and stings, that are usually melee-only. Only a few creatures spit venom, and adding range to others is a pain.
Despite that pain, natural venom is better, because venomfire exists. Well, actually, check that—venomfire is so absurd, that it’s often banned, so make sure it’s actually allowed at your table. If it’s not, the decision between natural venom and applied poison becomes a lot more even.
Natural venom
Below are options for getting natural venom, buffing natural venom, and adding range to the venomous melee attacks.
Venomfire
This is, basically, why you’re here, why you’re putting up with all the difficulties of adding range to your venomous attacks.
Venomfire is a ridiculous 3rd-level cleric or druid spell from Serpent Kingdoms that causes your “venom” (not really well-defined, but probably any natural “automatic” poison, as opposed to manually-applied poisons) to deal additional acid damage—a lot of it. For hours. And it doesn’t even care if the target actually fails the save against the venom, so you don’t have to worry about its DC (which is otherwise one of the huge problems with poisons).
Touch of Golden Ice
Realistically, this is probably a poor idea. This feat from Book of Exalted Deeds doesn’t technically involve poison—it’s a “ravage,” a sort of poison-but-technically-good-aligned-because-the-writers-were-hacks-who-misunderstood-alignment. That means it may not interact with other things that key off of “poison” per se. It also may not count as “venom” in that it’s supernatural. So it may not even trigger venomfire.
But if your DM rules that it does, things get interesting. Touch of Golden Ice applies this ravage to every one of your natural attacks and unarmed strikes—and you can get a lot of those. The DC is pitiful and the effect isn’t that great even if they fail, but with venomfire you don’t really care. And it’s just one feat. Getting range will be tricky, but do-able (see blood wind and throwing cheese, below).
Wild shape
Druid is a very-likely candidate here, because wild shape is so good. There are a lot of venomous forms you can take on. The fleshraker dinosaur (Monster Manual III) is a particularly juicy one, having pounce and poison on each of many attacks, though at higher levels you might look for better.
Animal Devotion
While generally a pretty good feat from Complete Champion, the primary reason it comes up here is because one of its options is to gain a venomous bite attack. It only lasts 1 minute/day unless you take Animal Devotion repeatedly or have (a lot of) uses of turn/rebuke undead to spend on it, so it isn’t actually good for that purpose, but until you get wild shape, it might be the best you can do. After you get wild shape, you’ll probably just use it for getting some flight in non-flying forms. But really, the only reason to take it is...
Spit Venom and Deadly Spittle
In addition to venomfire, Serpent Kingdoms also has the Spit Venom and Deadly Spittle feats. The former turns any “venom” into a ranged touch attack, while the latter turns any poison spit into a cone. With both and venomfire, you’ll have a 15-foot cone of fireball-level damage, but acid (less frequently resisted), at will, and no save.
Requirements are an issue here: you need a venomous bite for Spit Venom, and you need venomous spit for Deadly Spittle. Wild shape works, but you don’t get that until 5th, which is a miserable delay on actually getting these feats. This is the main purpose of Animal Devotion here: allowing you to take these feats earlier. If your campaign uses Unearthed Arcana flaws, you could have Animal Devotion, Spit Venom, and Deadly Spittle all at 1st. (If not, you can be human to get two of them and get Deadly Spittle at 3rd.)
The bigger problem with both Spit Venom and Deadly Spittle is that they take a standard action to use once. You’d really prefer to be applying venom—and thus venomfire—more often than that.
Blood wind
This spell from Spell Compendium can allow you to use natural weapons—like a fleshraker’s venomous claws—at range. Problem is, you have to cast it each turn you want to attack at range—even as a 1st-level spell, you’re probably going to run out of spell slots before you run out of enemies, like that. A wand of blood wind is probably necessary, though burning 15 gp per turn isn’t exactly great. You’ll also need to figure out how—blood wind isn’t a druid spell. You could dip cleric, sorcerer, or wizard, try to pick up the Magic domain somehow, or just figure out how to hit DC 20 on your Use Magic Device checks. You could also consider just being a cleric, particularly if you’re going the Touch of Golden Ice route.
Cheese throwing onto natural weapons??
The special weapon property throwing turns any weapon into a thrown weapon. If you can get it onto a natural weapon—e.g. with the kensai prestige class (Complete Warrior) or the necklace of natural attacks (Savage Species), it arguably allows you to throw your natural weapons. Some groups find this awesome and hilarious, while others find it cheesy and stupid—so you’ll want to check in to see if this is cool at your table. Note that you may have to get returning, too—you’re probably best off taking some levels in bloodstorm blade from Tome of Battle for that alongside a bunch of other thrown-weapon bonuses.
Applied poisons
Below are options for getting better at applying poisons, or getting poisons to apply in an economical way.
More than half of these come from Drow of the Underdark (not to be confused with Underdark, a separate supplement). Seriously, that books is really important to making poisons worthwhile.
Craft (poisonmaking)
This application of the Craft skill is discussed in Drow of the Underdark, and it’s important because it allows you to produce poisons for ⅙ their cost, instead of ⅓. That goes a long way towards saving your money.
Basically, no matter what else you do—aside from having your own natural venom—you’re probably going to wind up here for bulk poisons. There are some good low-level options, below, for even-cheaper poison, but the limitations on them mean you’ll probably want to start shelling out money for better poisons sooner or later.
“Milking” venom
Drow of the Underdark’s skill section also details how you can use Handle Animal to get venom out of a creature and use it as a poison. It makes an animal companion or similar an excellent source of low-level poisons.
Psionic minor creation
This 1st-level psionic power allows you to create any vegetative matter you like—which includes a lot of poisons. It’s available to 1st-level shaper psions. One of the best ways to get poisons in bulk.
Master of Poisons
Yet another option from Drow of the Underdark, this feat allows you to avoid the risk of poisoning yourself when applying poison to a weapon, and to poison a weapon as a swift action. The swift-action requirement limits you to one poison per turn (or, well, however many poisoned weapons you start the turn with, +1), but it’s still the best you can get. If you’re applying poisons to weapons, this is must-have.
Poison Spell
More from Drow of the Underdark, this metamagic feat allows you to apply poison to touch spells. This means melee, not ranged, touch attacks, but ask your DM if you can use Reach Spell and/or arcane reach to add range to those. The advantage here is that if you use it on a spell that allows multiple touches, like chill touch, you can apply one dose of poison several times. It also has the advantage of not costing an action (as long as you prepare spells), being a metamagic effect as part of casting the spell, though it does risk poisoning yourself (which makes poison use or Master of Poisons still valuable).
If your DM does not allow Reach Spell or arcane reach to work, unarmed strikes and natural weapons can deliver touch spells—so maybe blood wind or throwing cheese can help here. See the entries under venomous attacks for details.
Toxic weapons
A poison applied to a toxic weapon (Drow of the Underdark, because of course it is) applies to two attacks, instead of just one. Doubles the value of each of your poisons, and also helps with the action issues.

Snakebite is a 3rd level spell for Druids; that's going to be tricky to cast before Druid 5, at which point you already have Wildshape.

@Elliot I literally had the page open and still misremembered. Good point. Sigh, that’s awkward. Animal Devotion it is.
